# global question (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
admin = Tk()
a = 1

def up():
    global a
    a += 1

def upp():
    up()
    print a
print 'its ',a
buttton = Button(admin, text='up', command=upp)
buttton.pack()
mainloop()
```

I want to have the "its ",a go up each time i press the button. so kind of replay the code so that, its # would go up by one each time...help

Answer (score 4):

I tested this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import itertools

admin = Tk()
a = itertools.count(1).next


def upp():
    print a()

buttton = Button(admin, text='up', command=upp)
buttton.pack()
mainloop()
```

This will start a at a value of 1 and each time its printed it will add one more. So the first time you press it, it will display 1 in standard out.

Comment: tested and edited my sample. It seems to work as he requests, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: You were right to challenge me on my solution. I didnt test the idea to verify its correctness. I am relatively new to python, so having that sanity check is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work the way i wanted it to . i wanted it to print the +1 outside the function and then replay all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
def upp():
    up()
    print a
print 'its ',a
buttton = Button(admin, text='up', command=upp)
buttton.pack()
mainloop()
```

with

```
def upp():
    up()
    print 'its ', a
buttton = Button(admin, text='up', command=upp)
buttton.pack()
mainloop()
```

and it works as you want.

**Update:** Note that you dont need two functions. A simplified version:

```
from Tkinter import *
admin = Tk()
a = 0

def upp():
    global a
    a += 1
    print 'its ', a

buttton = Button(admin, text='up', command=upp)
buttton.pack()
mainloop()
```

anyway global variables should be avoided (see Alan answer for a better solution)